# How to resolve 'Something went wrong' error in Apple TestFlight

Tags: testflight, app-store-connect

I'm editing the 'Test Details' section for my app on TestFlight. When I select save after entering all details (Contact, Review Information, Description...) I end up with a generic error 'Something went wrong, please try again later."

What's the issue here and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to some special characters in one of the fields you are editing in the 'Test Details' section.

[A post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/309646#309646) at Apple Developer Forum mentions the use of emojis in the description as a cause for this error:

> it turns out that if you use an emoji, in my case it was (  ), TestFlight no longer works?!
>
> Having "(" and or ")" in the description causes this error.

In my case I copied my work **phone number** from the Contacts app on my Mac. **Entering it manually in the following format resolved the issue for me**:

*015111111111* instead of ‭*+49 151 11111111*